# Error in showing $\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{21}$ in the matrix representation

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

I read that the relation $\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{21}$ in the matrix representation but when I tried to work it out I don't see how.

$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}$ acts in the following way:

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|00\rangle=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|0\rangle|0\rangle=|0\rangle|0\rangle=|00\rangle$$

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|01\rangle=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|0\rangle|1\rangle=|0\rangle|1\rangle=|01\rangle$$

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|10\rangle=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|1\rangle|0\rangle=|1\rangle(-|0\rangle)=-|10\rangle$$

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|11\rangle=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|1\rangle|1\rangle=|1\rangle(-|1\rangle)=-|11\rangle$$

Which means its matrix representation is:

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{21}$ though acts as follows:

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{21}|00\rangle=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|0\rangle|0\rangle=|0\rangle|0\rangle=|00\rangle$$

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{21}|01\rangle=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|0\rangle|1\rangle=(-|0\rangle)|1\rangle=-|01\rangle$$

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{21}|10\rangle=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|1\rangle|0\rangle=|1\rangle|0\rangle=|10\rangle$$

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{21}|11\rangle=\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}|1\rangle|1\rangle=(-|1\rangle)|1\rangle=-|11\rangle$$

Which will give matrix representation:

$$\operatorname{CPHASE}_{21}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Obviously, the way I have done it has not produced the aforementioned identity, so where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gates you calculated are not controlled gates.

The $\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}$ and $\operatorname{CPHASE}_{21}$ you calculated are just $\sigma_z \otimes \mathbb{I}$ and $\mathbb{I} \otimes \sigma_z$ respectively. These are not controlled gates. 
A general controlled phase gates controlled on 1 is

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12} =   \vert 0 \rangle \langle 0 \vert \otimes \mathbb{I} + \vert 1 \rangle \langle 1 \vert \otimes R_{\phi},
\end{equation}

where, 
\begin{equation}
R_{\phi} = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 &
   0 \\
   0 &
   e^{i\phi} 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Which means $\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12}$ is
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\phi} 
\end{bmatrix}
You can similarly calculate the other one,
Now, even these gates are not equivalent, maybe you read that their action on some states are equivalent. Please provide the reference of your claim about the equivalency of the two gates.

**How to relate to $\operatorname{CNOT}_{12}$**

For $\phi = \pi$
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{CPHASE}_{12} =   \vert 0 \rangle \langle 0 \vert \otimes \mathbb{I} + \vert 1 \rangle \langle 1 \vert \otimes R_{\pi} = \vert 0 \rangle \langle 0 \vert \otimes \mathbb{I} + \vert 1 \rangle \langle 1 \vert \otimes \begin{bmatrix}
   1 &
   0 \\
   0 &
   -1 
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
A $\operatorname{CNOT}_{12}$ gate is 
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{CNOT}_{12} =   \vert 0 \rangle \langle 0 \vert \otimes \mathbb{I} + \vert 1 \rangle \langle 1 \vert \otimes \sigma_x = \vert 0 \rangle \langle 0 \vert \otimes \mathbb{I} + \vert 1 \rangle \langle 1 \vert \otimes \begin{bmatrix}
   0 &
   1 \\
   1 &
   0 
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

Which means,
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{CNOT}_{12} = (\mathbb{I} \otimes R^{\pi/2}_y) \cdot \operatorname{CPHASE}_{12} \cdot (\mathbb{I} \otimes R^{-\pi/2}_y)
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't understand how this matrix can be the $CNOT_{12}$ gate ( I'm not saying you're wrong but I don't understand) . We want the phase to be flipped if the first qubit is 1, so I would have thought the transformation would be $|\psi \rangle = c_{00}|00>+c_{01}|01>+c_{10}|10 \rangle +c_{11}|11\rangle \rightarrow c_{00}|00>+c_{01}|01>-c_{10}|10 \rangle -c_{11}|11\rangle$, but it looks to me as though the gate you provided will give $|\psi \rangle = c_{00}|00>+c_{01}|01>+c_{10}|10 \rangle +c_{11}|11\rangle \rightarrow c_{00}|00>+c_{01}|01>+c_{10}|10 \rangle -c_{11}|11\rangle$,

Comment: And the identity was from an assignment paper I only have a paper copy of. Note though that it was the second assignment we're on assignment 8 now, dealing with open quantum systems, so this isn't  a homework question I'm just going back over everything for exams

Comment: 1) For $\phi = \pi$ the above gate is controlled-z gate, you can  shift the basis of second system to make the gate equivalent to $CNOT_{12}$. I can edit my answer to show this explicitly if this doesn't make sense!

Comment: That would be so helpful thank you so much :) I'm just a little lost about this one XD

Comment: 2) I think you are confused what controlled phase gate does. A CNOT gate applies a NOT gate depending on the control, similarly a CPHASE gate applies a phase gate depending on the control. what you are doing (by changing phases)  is just a rotation operation its not controlled.

Comment: Yes I am confused I had thought that CNOT_{12}|10>=|11>, CPHASE_{12}|11>=-|11> etc#

Comment: The action of gates you are wrote are completely correct. Its the ones you didn't wrote. Look at it like this what does a NOT gate does, $\vert 0 \rangle \rightarrow \vert 1 \rangle$ and $\vert 1 \rangle \rightarrow \vert 0 \rangle$. Therefore a CNOT would $\vert 10 \rangle \rightarrow \vert 11 \rangle$ and $\vert 11 \rangle \rightarrow \vert 10 \rangle$. And I think you are perfectly clear with this concept.

Comment: But what does a phase gate do? It takes $\vert 0 \rangle \rightarrow \vert 0 \rangle$ and $\vert 1 \rangle \rightarrow  e^{i \phi}\vert 1 \rangle$. So what would a CPHASE gate do? I leave that upto you to answer.

Comment: Yes but then for $CPHASE_{12}$, I thought that it was supposed to change the phase of the second qubit if the first is one , so say we have $\phi=\pi$, Then shouldn't the action be under $CPHASE_{12}$ be , $|00>\rightarrow |00>,|01>\rightarrow |01>, |10>\rightarrow -|10> ,|11>\rightarrow - |11>$. This is the part I truly don't understand , as it seems $|01>\rightarrow |01>$under the transformation mentioned , above. If it's still unclear to me after this question then I'll have to ask my lecturer but is there any way you could try to clear this up for me first.

Comment: considering only tensor product I understand why it should be your answer , it's just considering it in the way I described it as considering the |xy> individually I don't understand how the two add up

Comment: Look at it this way, in a C-gate application the state of the first qubit is a flag of whether the gate will be applied or not, so $\vert 00 \rangle$  and $\vert 01 \rangle$ doesnt change since $\vert 0 \rangle$ on 1st qubit implies no action on 2nd. Then for $\vert 10 \rangle$ and $\vert 11 \rangle$ you apply the gate on the 2nd qubit state. Now, at this point i urge you to take a look at the phase gate in my answer, it does nothing to $\vert 0 \rangle$ state. Therefore for $\phi=\pi$, $\vert 10 \rangle \rightarrow \vert 10 \rangle$ and $ \vert 11 \rangle\ \rightarrow -\vert 11 \rangle$.

Comment: I am online for next 20 min or so, I am happy to answer your question via chat (although i have never used this feature before) But it would be easier back and forth.

Comment: Oh my gosh , I wasn't using the phase correctly , wow talk about blind . haha I totally understand now I had just been repeatedly making the same silly mistake and couldn't see past it . thank you for your patience :)

Comment: You are most welcome, now coming back to the question of the equivalency of the two matrices, I believe you are missing some key information from the question

Comment: Thank you for your kind offer to help me in chat aswell :) I had been confusing the X and Z gates , in the sense that X affects |0> and |1> while Z only affects |1>

Comment: In literal sense yes, Z affects only $\vert 1 \rangle$, but to be perfectly clear it does affect $\vert 0 \rangle$. Since, $\vert 1 \rangle$ and $\vert 0 \rangle$ are eigenvectors of Z they are multiplied by their respective eigenvalues,which happen to be +1 for $\vert 0 \rangle$. Just to nit pick

Comment: Propose the conditional two-qubit gate, CPHASE12, that ﬂips the phase of the second qubit if the ﬁrst qubit is in the state |1>,  Show that the following relation for the controlled-PHASE gate CPHASE12 = CPHASE21 in the matrix representation. That was the exact wording of the question but I can just ask my lecturer if he had forgot something if it makes no sense. And no, nitpicking is good it helps one to learn.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a scenario where this would be true, unless the equivalency is implied for application on certain states. I have to head off now, good luck with the exams!

Comment: I'll ask my lecturer for clarification. Thanks !

Comment: @can'tcauchy just curious on any update on this!

Comment: @can'tcauchy please avoid long discussions in the comments, as comments are not really designed for that. It would be great if you (or the answerer here) could edit your posts with the new questions/clarifications that arose from the discussion, if there are any. If there aren't other things to clarify, you could mark the answer as accepted to make this clear to others.